# iTunes Search API - correct language of results

Tags: itunes-search-api

I'm using the iTunes API and I have a problem. I'm searching in den German store (parameter country=de) but the description in the resultset is English. Does someone know a workaround to get the German description. It's available, the iTunes store direct shows the German description. It tried to use the "lang" parameter, but it's defined that only "en_us" & "ja_jp" are possible values. I depend on the [official documentation of apple](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html).

Here is the API Call: http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=angry+birds&country=de&entity=software

And for the first result, here is the detail page in iTunes web: http://itunes.apple.com/de/app/angry-birds/id343200656?mt=8&uo=4

---

Sorry, I got it by myself...

You have to use

> http://itunes.apple.com/**de**/search?term=angry+birds&country=de&entity=software

Answer (score 3, accepted):

prepend the URL path with `/de` like so:

```
http://itunes.apple.com/de/search?term=angry+birds&country=de&entity=software
```