# Search Itunes API by Subtitle Language

Tags: python, python-requests, itunes, itunes-api

I am trying to use iTunes API to find movies with Russian subtitles (it appears that simply searching Apple Movies app by language is not an option, which baffles me).

It looks like there is not explicit "subtitle language" search parameter available, so I was trying to use `languageTerm` parameter. I am using python 3 `requests` library. However, even if I search for movies with English language term, I get 0 results back:

```
import requests
url = 'https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=english&media=all&attribute=languageTerm&limit=1'

response = requests.get(url)
response.json()
```

Am I constructing the url incorrectly? Is `lanugageTerm` meant to be used differently? Any help is greatly appreciated. API doc I am referencing: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/iTuneSearchAPI/Searching.html#//apple_ref/doc/

Comment: Welcome. Have you looked at [iTunes Search API - correct language of results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799566/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iTunes Search API - correct language of results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799566/itunes-search-api-correct-language-of-results)

Comment: @Tedinoz I am not looking to change language of returned results, but actually searching for available movie subtitle languages. Some movies have closed caption/subtitles in English only, some have various other languages. My goal is to search for movies that have Russian subtitles available

Comment: Yes, I did realise that. The relevance/importance of the other post was the discussion of the search terms in the URL.

Comment: I agree that the `lang` parameter appears to refer to the language of the search results. While the language of a given movie and/or its subtitles may be accessible from within iTunes, that information does not seem to be included in the search terms of the [iTunes Search API](https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/#searching).

Comment: it seems like movie/entity language would be accessible through `attribute=languageTerm` but somehow even with English I get no results back

Comment: Not so sure; I looks more like `languageTerm` is only available from an entity type of `all`. I've just been testing with "Ryan+Reynolds" and it returns all the Deadpool material but zero language info despite the fact that the Itunes Store shows that there are sub-titles in about 30 foreign languages ("Russian",not being one, BTW).